# Identifying a SMD component (marking CWAJ, possibly a DC-DC converter)

Tags: identification, dc-dc-converter

Please, can anyone identify this SMD?

I think it's a "DC to DC step converter", but I can't find this "**CWAJ**" label anywhere.

[image]

[image]

---

[image: shema]

Here is my measure. i hope that is a correct :-)

Comment: What's the power supply voltage that this board requires? That could help us determine whether it's a buck or boost converter IC.

Comment: supply voltage is DC - 12V/2A

Comment: I can't find anything right away, unfortunately. Could you buzz this out for us with a multimeter? I need to know which pins of the IC are: Ground, 12V supply input, switch node (connected to the large inductor), feedback (connected to the other side of the inductor via a resistive divider), and potentially enable (likely also connected to 12V).

Comment: yes, I'll try to measure it at the weekend

Comment: when i painted it, it looks like this IO could be 2A, 24V Synchronous
Step-Down Converter  EV5027

Comment: As far as i saw in Google this board from ip-camera and this is step-down DC-DC converter. On other pictures (also in Google) i saw other markings and they all belong to Joulwatt dc-dc converters (if you need this screens, let me know). Since "almost all" dc-dc converters with "same typical" schematic have same pinout you can try to use JW5027 from https://www.joulwatt.com/en/proinfo_3417.html.

Comment: And are you sure that between pin 1 and pin 6 actually resistor? It should be a capacitor between SW and BST pins

Comment: It’s not the first one: https://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic3840829.html  and https://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic3886492.html, you can buy a new board on Aliexpress for 10€: https://m.nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005004170512261.html?gatewayAdapt=gloPc2nldMsite.

Comment: If the goal is to fix the board you could replace the whole DC-DC with a Traco/Recom/other canned buck regulator, this will be faster than figuring out the exact chip. It looks like it has a feedback pin, so you'd need to find a replacement with the same FB pin voltage, besides pinout. Also you should check if the rest of the board still works before attempting repair, who knows if it shorted input to output while burning, the rest of the chips may be fried too.